# Razor view engine data entry form

Tags: css, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I Am from a WPF/XAML background and I'm trying to get my head into MVC. I am wondering if I want to create a data capture form, would you use **table** or **div** to structure the labels and dropdowns/textboxes etc.?

I ask because the template provided has all stacked one on top of another and wastes valuable screen area. I want to have my **labels** for **Title**, **Forename**, **Surname** all on one line/row and the same for data capture elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `div` to structure your layout.
Also you can use some grid layout framework (like in [Twiter Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), see *Grid system*). If you have WPF background - it can simulate to some extent `Grid` panel from WPF in HTML world.

Answer (score 0):

In **HTML** table tags should be used for **[Tabular data](http://www.w3.org/WAI/wcag-curric/sam48-0.htm)**; layout of forms etc should be done using `Div` / `Span` tags for structure and `CSS` to control the structure.

Take a looks at the link below for input form structure example:

[Differents way to structure html inputs and labels in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151148/differents-way-to-structure-html-inputs-and-labels-in-a-form)

[Best way to structure a two column html form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728162/best-way-to-structure-a-two-column-html-form)

http://aceinfowayindia.com/blog/2009/06/how-create-good-looking-form-without-table/

It's not only cleaner to use Div, but it also makes the page more accessible according to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/) rules.